# selected value cannot be set

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox which gets its Items from some scan function.

If the user select an element, in the next time, the user's chosen item should be selected (if it is present on the scan function output). The problem is that I cannot select it.

Here is the declaration of the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Name="SerialPortNames" Text="{Binding Name}" IsEditable="False"/>
```

and here what I have tried so far:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string portNameSetting = Settings.Default["SerialPortName"].ToString();

    SerialPortNames.ItemsSource = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

    foreach (string SerialPortNameItem in SerialPortNames.Items)
    {
        if (SerialPortNameItem == portNameSetting)
        {
            SerialPortNames.Text = SerialPortNameItem; // why this is not working
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

by debugging this, I get the item selected in the combobox, but it seems that something override it and it is empty!

Comment: Does the SerialPortNames.ItemsSource contains SerialPortNameItem?

Comment: what is the value of SerialPortNameItem , that you are setting to SerialPortNames.Text?

Comment: You're binding Text="{Binding Name}" and setting iseditable false. Meaning you can't set the Text property. Which you then also try and set in code. At least 2 of those are a bad idea.

Comment: @Andy, I removed "iseditable" from the xaml, but the problem persist

Comment: Remove  Text="{Binding Name}" from Combobox

Comment: @ Justin CI, it works! think you. so the binding override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you Binded the Text propery and also setting it from code behind

Remove Text="{Binding Name}"  from the combobox

```
 <ComboBox  Width="200" Height="200" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" Name="SerialPortNames"  IsEditable="False"/>
```